# Why does Armadillo produce NaN in eigenvectors?

Tags: armadillo

I am using Armadillo C++ library to perform the eigen decomposition of a Hermitian matrix `R` of size 49x49. The resulting eigenvectors have NaN columns sometimes. When I perform the same decomposition in matlab there is no such issue.

My Armadillo code is something like this:

```
cx_mat R = (S_n_centered * S_n_centered.t()) / S_n.n_cols;
cx_mat E;
vec d;
bool success = eig_sym(d,E,R);
```

For example when R is [this](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25752377/), the eigenvectors corresponding to the three largest eigenvalues are [these](https://paste.ubuntu.com/25752391/). The success flag is true and eigenvalues are correct (almost the same as in Matlab).

I am using Armadillo version 7.960.0 and using blas_win64_MT.dll and lapack_win64_MT.dll both of which are included in the examples folder.

Decomposing the same Matrix in Matlab doesn't cause any issues but the eigenvectors are all different.

Could this be a bug in Armadillo or the Lapack library?

Comment: Works fine under Linux and Mac (no NaNs). Maybe it's an issue with the Windows version of lapack?

Comment: Any news for your problem? I am facing to the same one.

Comment: I don't remember clearly but I think it was an error caused due to some flag in Armadillo that in turn caused 32bit version of some intermediate function being called. Sadly I do not have access to code now. I think I just placed a break point and at some point inside the Armadillo stack itself there was this function that was supposed to wrap calls to Lapack. Check all Armadillo flags and read the documentation (in the header file containing the flags).